# jQuery - Endless Carousel from scratch - Next and Previous Arrow behave strangely

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I am trying to create a content slider for a website. The slider canvas area can only show 3 items at a time, while there may be 4 or more items.

---

**Please See JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qDUVw/**

*(You'll want to widen the display section to at least 1000px)*

---

In my mind, the way it works is this....

Have the first 3 items visible. All remaining items will be hidden (due to overflow), off to the right of the first 3 (visible) items.

When the user clicks "Next" I am animating all items to the left by 338 pixels (the width of the individual items). Once the animation is done, I am locating the first item (which is now off-screen to the left), and moving it to the end. I am doing this both with `.animate()` as well as `.appendTo`. This ensures it is visibly at the end, as well as at the end of the DOM structure.

When the use clicks "Previous" I am **before anything** grabbing the last item, and moving it to the first position (both with `.animate()` and `prependTo()`) and then performing the animation of all items to the right, so the new first item is in place before the animation.

HOWEVER...

When you click next a few times, it seems to work OK..
if you reload and click prev a few times.. it also works OK..
When you click a combination of the two buttons, strange things start to happen and I am not sure why. The items seem to be moving out of turn and to the wrong locations.

I am having a very hard time finding the issue here. Any advice would be GREATLY appreciated!!

**CSS**

```
body{background:#000;}
#poster_holder{
    margin-top:5px;
    overflow:hidden;
    position:relative;
    height: 500px;
    width:1000px;
}
#poster_holder #shade_left{
    width:49px;
    height:510px;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    position:absolute;
    background:url(http://s10.postimg.org/km0bl8let/shade_left.png?noCache=1373557653) repeat-y;
    z-index:990;
    cursor:pointer;
}


#poster_holder #shade_right{
    width:49px;
    height:510px;
    top:0;
    right:0;
    position:absolute;
    background:url(http://s10.postimg.org/d4r460vvp/shade_right.png?noCache=1373557653) repeat-y;
    z-index:990;
    cursor:pointer;
}
#poster_holder #shade_left .arrow,
#poster_holder #shade_right .arrow{
    margin-top: 200px;
    text-align:center;
    color:#fff;
}

#poster_holder #shade_left:hover .arrow,
#poster_holder #shade_right:hover .arrow{

}    
#poster_slider{
    width:1400px;
    height:500px;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:900;
    overflow:hidden;
}    
#poster_holder .item{
    height:500px;
    width:323px;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    cursor:pointer;

}
#poster_holder .item:last-child{
    margin-right:0px !important;        
}
```

**JS**

```
$('#shade_right').click(function(e){  //NEXT
    $('#poster_holder .item').animate(
        {left: '-=338'},
        function(){
            var i = $('#poster_holder .item:first');
            var x = $('#poster_holder .item:last').position().left + 338;
            i.animate({'left':x+'px'},1).appendTo('#poster_slider');                
        }
    );                 
});
$('#shade_left').click(function(e){   //PREV
    var i = $('#poster_holder .item:last');
    i.prependTo('#poster_slider').animate({'left':'-338px'},1);
    $('#poster_holder .item').animate({
        left: '+=338'
    });
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="poster_holder">
    <div id="poster_slider">
         <div class="item" id="item-1" style="left:0px;background:#ff0;"></div> 
         <div class="item" id="item-2" style="left:338px;background:#0ff;"></div>
         <div class="item" id="item-3" style="left:676px;background:#f0f;"></div>
         <div class="item" id="item-4" style="left:1014px;background:#00f;"></div>
    </div>

    <!-- Black Gradient Left & Prev Button -->
    <div id="shade_left"><div class="arrow"><img src="http://s11.postimg.org/5ttem5r0f/arrow_prev.png?noCache=1373557626" /></div></div>
    <!-- Black Gradient Right & Next Button -->
    <div id="shade_right"><div class="arrow"><img src="http://s21.postimg.org/bdyks7rwj/arrow_next.png?noCache=1373557551" /></div></div>    

</div>
```

Comment: Always post the relevant code *in the question itself*, don't just link. (Not even to jsFiddle) Why: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118392/add-stack-overfow-faq-entry-or-similar-for-putting-code-in-the-question

Comment: I think that’d be called a carousel, rather than a slider.

Comment: Isn't a carousel a type of content slider?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the culprit! when clicking `next`, my callback was being called 4 times - one for each animated item. I had to change my `next` procedure to this to ensure it was only called once at the end.

```
    $('#shade_right').click(function(e){  //NEXT
        $('.posterItem')
            .animate({left: '-=338'})
            .promise()
            .done(function(){
                var firstItem = $('.posterItem:first');
                var pos = $('.posterItem:last').position().left + 338;
                firstItem.animate({'left':pos+'px'},1).appendTo('#poster_slider');                
            })                 
    });
```